# cuda 3.2 on vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

Basically, I try to compile the test project from [this guide](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/02/24/how-to-run-cuda-in-visual-studio-2010/). I plan to use CUDA 3.2 and I'm on 64bit Win7. I followed the guide step by step, but I get a rather cryptic error message when I try to rebuild:

> Fehler 1   error MSB3721: Der Befehl ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -ccbin "bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\include"    --keep-dir "x64\Debug\" -maxrregcount=32  --machine 64 --compile  -D_NEXUS_DEBUG -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MTd " -o "x64\Debug\kernel.obj" "D:\unsorted\VS2010Test\VS2010Test\VS2010Test\kernel.cu" -clean" wurde mit Code -1 beendet.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 3.2.targets  352

"wurde mit Code -1 beendet" is german for "ended returning code -1". Has anyone experienced this error? Any pointers?

Comment: This can be considered solved. This mess above basically translates to: install VS2008 with 64 bit compilers (not installed by default, even if you're on a 64 bit system).

Comment: Matthias: Can you mark this as answered so that it doesn't clutter the list of unanswered questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be considered solved (c.f. above)